# Reputation points for comments

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, comments

Is there any chance that comments with upvotes will be counted to reputation?
Sometimes people comments are very helpful (there are situations where more than answer).

If it isn't good idea please write why? I'm just want know and here is probably good place for it. If not just tell me and I will delete my post.

Comment: Sorry for this duplicate but I've tried find this topic and cannot, that I write this question. Thanks for link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, comments are second-class citizens by intention. *Stack Exchange* is about *Questions and Answers* and not about comments.

Comments are only for clarification and so on and should not count towards your reputation.

Comment: So let's say someone write code for answer. This code isn't working as author want, so he write it in comment with providing information what is wrong using this code. So author of answer in second comment write something that: "change this line to ..." Now the alone answer isn't good. It's good only with this comment. So maybe add some additional mark to comment which was helpful or something that?

Comment: This is why you can edit posts

Comment: Users are encouraged to edit the existing answer in that case to make it work without the comments.

Comment: Ok people. Thanks for answers. It makes sense.